# Class method with google maps event listener run external function

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Sorry about the question title, it was hard to find a good one...

I have a class to handle google maps and one of my methods is to create a custom control:

```
// method:
Map.prototype.addButton = function (order, onCLickEvent) {
    var that = this;
    var buttonUI = $.get('/templates/order-button.html', function (data) {
        var button = $(data)[0];
        $(button).attr('id', order.id);
        $(button).find('span:eq(1)').text('#' + order.id);

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(button, 'click', function() {
            onCLickEvent;
        });
    });
}
```

As you can see I added a `click` event. That click should open a modal window.

When I use the method I'm doing:

```
var map = new Map();
map.addButton(order, openMyModal());
```

Unfortunately it open the modal as soon the page load.

I tried to do this as well:

```
var map = new Map();
map.addButton(order, function() {
  openMyModal();
});
```

So, my question is, how can I attach my open modal window function to the google maps event listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var map = new Map();
map.addButton(order, openMyModal());
```

should be

```
var map = new Map();
map.addButton(order, openMyModal);
```

You want to pass the function, not the result of the function as the second parameter

and

```
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(button, 'click', function() {
        onCLickEvent;
    });
```

should be

```
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(button, 'click', function() {
        onCLickEvent();
    });
```

Here you want to execute the passed in function